# i can not display good topics in good category

Tags: php, sql

I am annoyed because i'm trying to make a forum and I can not select the right categories in my SQL query.

My database is articulate like that :
`CATEGORIES (id, category_name, category_description) TOPICS (id, titre, contenu, id_auteur, pseudo_auteur, image_auteur, date_publication, categorie)`

I managed to display the categories in my index.php but when I try to display the topics that match the right category, I can not select them.

For example, if I have three topics in 3 different categories, I can not display the "category" that comes from topics, in a category that comes from categories, like "category.php?id=1".

Thanks for your help!

edit: my code :

```html
<?php
session_start();
require('actions/topics/showAllTopicsAction.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/style.css">
<?php include 'includes/head.php'; ?>

<body>
    <?php include 'includes/navbar.php'; ?>
    <br><br>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-between">
            <div> <button type="button" class="btn btn-shadow btn-wide btn-primary"> <span class="btn-icon-wrapper pr-2 opacity-7"> <i class="fa fa-plus fa-w-20"></i> </span> New thread </button> </div>
            <div class="col-10 col-md-3 p-0 mb-3"> <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..."> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card mb-3">
            <div class="card-header bg-dark text-white pl-0 pr-0">
                    <div class="col ml-3">Sujets</div>
                    <div class="col-4 text-muted">
                        <div class="row no-gutters align-items-center">
                            <div class="col-4">Réponses</div>
                            <div class="col-8">Dernier post</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>

            <?php while ($topic = $getAllTopics->fetch()) { ?>
                <div class="card-body py-3">
                    <div class="row no-gutters align-items-center">
                        <div class="col"> <a href="#" class="text-big" data-abc="true">
                                <a href="article.php?id=<?= $topic['id']; ?>"> <?= $topic['titre']; ?></a>
                                <div class="text-muted small mt-1">Publié par <a href="profile.php?id=<?= $topic['id_auteur']; ?>"><?= $topic['pseudo_auteur']; ?></a> le <?= $topic['date_publication']; ?></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="d-none d-md-block col-4">
                            <div class="row no-gutters align-items-center">
                                <div class="col-4">12</div>
                                <div class="media col-8 align-items-center"> <img src="assets/img/anonymous.png" alt="" class="d-block ui-w-30 rounded-circle">
                                    <div class="media-body flex-truncate ml-2">
                                        <div class="line-height-1 text-truncate">?Titre du sujet?</div> <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="text-muted small text-truncate" data-abc="true">?Auteur?</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php } ?>

        </div>

        <nav>
            <ul class="pagination mb-5">
                <li class="page-item disabled"><a class="page-link" href="javascript:void(0)" data-abc="true">«</a></li>
                <li class="page-item active"><a class="page-link" href="javascript:void(0)" data-abc="true">1</a></li>
                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="javascript:void(0)" data-abc="true">2</a></li>
                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="javascript:void(0)" data-abc="true">3</a></li>
                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="javascript:void(0)" data-abc="true">»</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

```html
<?php

require('actions/database.php');

//Récupérer les topics par défaut sans recherche
$getAllTopics = $bdd->query('SELECT * FROM topics WHERE categorie ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,5');
```

Comment: `WHERE categorie` should be `WHERE categorie = $id`

Comment: @Barmar i have a message error when i try that :/

Comment: Of course you need to set `$id = $_GET['id']`

Comment: @Barmar i just tried that `if(isset($_GET['id']) AND !empty($_GET['id'])){


    $getAllTopics = $_GET['id'];}


$getAllTopics = $bdd->query('SELECT * FROM topics WHERE categorie = id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,5')`
;` and don't work :/

Comment: @Barmar i'm deeply sorry sir but still don't work... i just tried that `if (!isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = intval($_GET['id']);
    $getAllTopics = $bdd->query("SELECT * FROM topics WHERE categorie = $id ORDER BY id DESC limit 5");
    $getAllTopics->execute(array($idOfTheCategory));;
}`

Comment: What is `$bdd`?

Comment: What is `$idOfTheCategory`? `execute()` is used with prepared statements. Does `$bdd->query()` return a prepared statement or does it execute the query?

Comment: @Barmar my database

Comment: I mean what kind of database connection is it? mysqli or PDO?

Comment: @Barmar it's PDO i have this error `Warning
: Undefined variable $getAllTopics in
C:\xampp\htdocs\Forum\category.php
on line
30`

Comment: @Barmar thanks !! does my html is good with your code?

Comment: That's left as an exercise for you. There are many tutorials on creating HTML tables from query results.

Comment: @Barmar A HOURS AGO I JUST FOUND A SOLUTION !!!! `if(isset($_GET['id']) AND !empty($_GET['id'])){ $id = $_GET['id']; $getAllTopics = $bdd->query("SELECT * FROM topics WHERE categorie = $id ORDER BY id DESC limit 5"); }`

Answer (score 1):

You need to substitute the `id` parameter into the query.

```
if (!isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = intval($_GET['id']);
    $statement = $bdd->query("SELECT * FROM topics WHERE categorie = ? ORDER BY id DESC limit 5");
    $statement->execute([$id]);
    $rows = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    // display the results from $rows
}
```